# PHP - check if string is similar to pattern

Tags: php, regex

In PHP there is the `levenshtein`-method, right?

With it you can check how similar two strings are.

But is there a way that you have a pattern (regEx) that you compare with a string?

So let's say you have the pattern: `L234X567PP`  All of the Numbers are changeable. Just the letters must be there (and at exactly the same position)

So now you have some Strings:
`L000X000PP`
`L987X123PP`
Those should be valid.

`B000X678XX`
This is not valid but `levenshtein` detects a similarity and could ask to correct the wrong letters (is that possible?)

How can you do this with PHP?

Answer (score 2):

An interesting concept, but why not try this?

```
if( preg_match("/^L\d{3}X\d{3}PP$/",$input)) { /* all ok! */ }
elseif( preg_match("/^[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z][A-Z]$/i",$input)) { /* letters were wrong */ }
// ... continue defining possible errors manually
```

Comment: That is a nice idea. I will try that out.

And thanks to the others as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this using PHP. Here is the regex you would use for your specified pattern:

```
$regex = '/^L[0-9]{3}X[0-9]{3}PP$/';
$input = 'L000X000PP';
if (preg_match($regex, $input) == 1) {
    echo "Matches!";
} else {
    echo "Does Not Match!"
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question of "almost matching"?

Answer (score 1):

That is where [**`soundex function`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) steps in. See this code snippet:

```
$str1 = "L000X000PP";
$str2 = "L987X123PP";
$_str1 = soundex ($str1);
$_str2 = soundex ($str2);

var_dump($_str1);
var_dump($_str2);
var_dump($_str1 == $_str2);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
string(4) "L210"
string(4) "L210"
bool(true)
```

Comment: thank you. I will try that out. But I think function could be problematic at some point because of the pronunciation. 
But I will try it, maybe it helps :)

Comment: This may turn out to be pretty useful for you as even `L987654321X1234578PP` produces same `L210` output.